# Prevent R from using virtual memory on unix/linux?

Tags: linux, r, unix

### Short version

Is there a way to prevent R from ever using any virtual memory on a unix machine? Whenever it happens it is because I screwed up and I then want to abort the computation.

### Longer version

I am working with a big datasets on a powerful computer shared with several other people. Sometimes I set off commands that requires more RAM than is available, which causes R to start swapping and eventually freeze the whole machine. Normally I can solve this by setting a `ulimit` in my `~/.bashrc`

```
ulimit -m 33554432 -v 33554432  # 32 GB RAM of the total 64 GB
```

which causes R to throw an error and abort when trying to allocate more memory than is available. However, if I make a misstake of this sort when parallelizing (typically using the `snow` package) the `ulimit` has no effect and the machine crashes anyway. I guess that is because `snow` launches the workers as separate processes that are not run in bash. If I instead try to set the `ulimit` in my `~/.Rprofile` I just get an error:

```
> system("ulimit -m 33554432 -v 33554432")
ulimit: 1: too many arguments
```

Could someone help me figure out a way to accomplish this?

### Side track

Why can I not set a `ulimit` of 0 virtual memory in `bash`?

```
$ ulimit -m 33554432 -v 0
```

If I do it quickly shuts down.

Comment: See [my answer to the linked question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24475329/946850) for an R package that allows setting an `ulimit` for a running R sesion.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When you run `system("ulimit")` that is executing in a child process. The parent does not inherit the `ulimit` from the parent. (This is analgous to doing `system("cd dir")`, or `system("export ENV_VAR=foo")`.

Setting it in the shell from which you launch the environment is the correct way.  The limit is not working in the parallel case most likely because it is a per-process limit, not a global system limit.

On Linux you can configure strict(er) overcommit accounting which tries to prevent the kernel from handling out a `mmap` request that cannot be backed by physical memory.

This is done by tuning the sysctl parameters `vm.overcommit_memory` and `vm.overcommit_ratio`. (Google about these.)

This can be an effective way to prevent thrashing situations. But the tradeoff is that you lose the benefit that overcommit provides when things are well-behaved (cramming more/larger processes into memory).

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply! I had no idea `system` started a child process, but thought it called its parent. The sysctl solution sounds interesting, especially if it can be set to only limit certain users or groups, so I'll look into it.