# How to increase memory allocation for R in OS X? (Not Windows)

Tags: r, macos, memory

I got iMac 5K (OS X 10.10.4) and installed 32GB RAM to analyze big data with R(3.2.1). However I found only about 1GB RAM was used for R session and it took so long time to handle my data. How can I increase memory allocation for R in OS X? `memory.limit()` function doesn't work in OS X.

Comment: Thanks, but above posting is for Windows users not for OS X. memory.limit() function does not work in OS X, it returns error.

Comment: You need to use `ulimit`, q.v. [this SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12582793/limiting-memory-usage-in-r-under-linux).

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Doesn't that question ask how to limit R's memory use? As far as I know [a normal 64 bits build of R doesn't have (practical) memory limits](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Memory-limits.html), unless there are limits imposed by the OS, which can be checked using `ulimit`.