# Alternative to R's `memory.size()` in linux?

Tags: r, linux, memory

`R`'s `memory.size()` is a Windows only. For other functions (such as `windows()`) the help page gives pointer to non-windows counterparts.

But for `memory.size()` I could find no such pointers.

So here is my question: is there a function to do the same as `memory.size()` but in linux?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Using *pryr* library:

```
library("pryr")

mem_used()
# 27.9 MB

x <- mem_used()
x
# 27.9 MB
class(x)
# [1] "bytes"
```

Result is the same as @RHertel's answer, with *pryr* we can assign the result into a variable.

```
system('grep MemTotal /proc/meminfo')
# MemTotal:       263844272 kB
```

To assign to a variable with system call, use `intern = TRUE`:

```
x <- system('grep MemTotal /proc/meminfo', intern = TRUE)
x
# [1] "MemTotal:       263844272 kB"
class(x)
# [1] "character"
```

Answer (score 15):

I think that this should be handled by the operating system. There is no built-in limit that I know of; if necessary, R will use all the memory that it can get.

To obtain information on the total and/or on the available memory in linux, you can try

```
system('grep MemTotal /proc/meminfo')
```

or

```
system('free -m')
```

or

```
system('lshw -class memory')
```

The last command will complain that you should run this as super-user and it will give a warning that the output may not be accurate; but from my experience it will still provide a fairly useful output.

---

To obtain information on the memory usage of a running R script one could either monitor the currently used resources by starting `top` in a separate terminal, or use, e.g., the following system call from within the R script:

```
system(paste0("cat /proc/",Sys.getpid(),"/status | grep VmSize"))
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks! But I am under the impression that `memory.size()` gives the memory footprint of the R proc and that the commands you gave give the memory limits assigned to R (something more akin to R/windows` `memory.limit()` command)

Comment: @user189035 There seems to be a misunderstanding. There's no memory limit assigned to an R process except for the total available memory. I edited the answer to include a possibility to display the memory used by a running R process. Hope this helps.

Comment: The memory.limit() command provides the total size of the machine's memory to an R script. Commands involving system() do not provide anything to an R script, they simply print stuff on the terminal. Completely useless for controlling an R script.

Comment: @Argent `memory.limit()` is Windows-specific. The OP asked specifically about Linux. As I write in the answer, the system calls can help to "obtain information", and not to provide anything to an R script. Please read carefully before downvoting.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, `memory.size()` and `memory.limit()` is not working in linux/unix.
I can suggest **unix** package.

To increase the memory limit in linux:

```
install.packages("unix") 
library(unix)
rlimit_as(1e12)  #increases to ~12GB
```

You can also check the memory with this:

```
rlimit_all()
```

for detailed information:
https://rdrr.io/cran/unix/man/rlimit.html

also you can find further info here:
[limiting memory usage in R under linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12582793/limiting-memory-usage-in-r-under-linux)