# Can an R script obtain the machine's memory size?

Tags: r, linux, memory-management

Is there a way for an R program to obtain the size of the machine's memory, when running on Linux?

In Windows the function to use is memory.size(), but when I run this on Linux it generates an error.

I can run `system('free')`, and this will produce a nice display, but the return value is 0, indicating, I suppose, success... but nothing about the size of memory.

**Note:** The goal is for an R script to obtain, and use, the total size of a machine's memory. Printing memory info to the terminal, using `system()`, is not useful.

Comment: @zx8754  Wrong. That so-called duplicate does not answer my question. Please re-read my question, carefully, and delete your duplicate flag.

Comment: OK, fair enough, I added linux solution where we can assign the result into a variable. Please refer to my answer [here from linked post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57035805/680068).