# Increasing memory limit in R for Mac

Tags: r, macos, memory

I have been looking at solutions posted online on how to increase the memory limit for R but these solutions seem to only work for [windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1395229/increasing-or-decreasing-the-memory-available-to-r-processes) or [linux systems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12582793/limiting-memory-usage-in-r-under-linux).

I am using Mac Mojave version 10.14.5, 8GB memory, 2.3 GHz Intel Core i5. My R studio is 64bit, version 1.1.453

Here's the report from the gc function:

```
> gc()
           used  (Mb) gc trigger   (Mb) limit (Mb)  max used   (Mb)
Ncells  6453699 344.7   11897884  635.5         NA  11897884  635.5
Vcells 44221701 337.4  179064532 1366.2       7168 219267441 1672.9
```

I am wondering why the limit for the Ncells and Vcells are so low -- 635.5Mb and 1672.9Mb? Does this mean R is only currently using that amount of memory? This is my suspicion and so I want to increase its limit.

What I am trying to do is: Merge a dataframe with 227,795 rows with another dataframe that has the same number of rows but with different columns. This is giving me an error:

```
Error: vector memory exhausted (limit reached?)
```

This error is also occurring when I try to build a large matrix of distances between 227,796 sets of coordinates.

Does anyone have any solutions to increase R's memory limit in mac? It would be great if there is a `memory.limit()` version for Mac.

Comment: Suggested dupe: [R on MacOS Error: vector memory exhausted (limit reached?)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51295402/903061)

Comment: Also, other things you don't mention in the question so I want to check--what else do you have open and using memory? What does your activity monitor utility show? When you say you want to merge a data frame with 227,795 with another that has different columns, are you merging on anything?? If you're doing a cross join, that would be a 52 Trillion row result, which will exhaust the memory of much larger systems than yours. What are you merging on? How many duplicate keys are there in each? Are you using `data.table` for the most memory efficient joins, or something else?