# Out of memory on R using linux but not on Windows

Tags: r, linux, memory, crash, large-files

I'm trying to manage large datasets or files (e.g., GeoTIFF) on plain R (via terminal) or RStudio (1.4.1106), but both apps crash every time on Linux (Manjaro, x64, core i7, and 8 GB RAM) for some scripts (especially when a raster data is plotted using ggplot2 to produce a high-quality map, as well as a lmer function with random factors using a csv file with ~3000 rows and 6 columns). Probably the issue refers to memory management since all the memory is consumed. To overcome, I tried two packages to limit/increase the memory size, such as "unix" and "RAppArmor". However, if the memory size is limited, all your available RAM was exhausted and the famous message "cannot allocate a vector..." is shown. On the other hand, if the memory size is increased to high levels, R/RStudio simply crashes. On Windows, the following code works like a charm to increase memory size (only needed to plot a raster into ggplot2):

```
    if(.Platform$OS.type == "windows") withAutoprint({
    memory.size()
    memory.size(TRUE)
    memory.limit()
    })
    memory.limit(size=56000)
```

However, this function does not work for Linux systems. As stated before, I used the two functions below to manage the RAM memory on Manjaro:

```
    library(ulimit)
    memory_limit(10000)
```

Or

```
    library(RAppArmor)
    rlimit_as(1e10)
```

Please find below a reproducible code similar to mine, including raster properties. The first six lines are used on Windows to increase memory:

```
    #if(.Platform$OS.type == "windows") withAutoprint({
    #  memory.size()
    #  memory.size(TRUE)
    #  memory.limit()
    #})
    #memory.limit(size=56000)

    library(rgdal)
    library(raster)
    library(tidyverse)
    library(sf)
    library(rnaturalearth)
    library(rnaturalearthdata)
    library(viridis)
    library(ggspatial)

    test <- raster(nrows = 8280, ncols = 5760, xmn = -82, xmx = -34, ymn = -57, ymx = 12)
    vals <-  1:ncell(test)
    test <- setValues(test, vals)
    test
    names(test)

    testpts <-  rasterToPoints(test, spatial = TRUE)
    testdf  <- data.frame(testpts)
    rm(testpts, test)
    str(testdf)

    polygons_brazil <- ne_countries(country = "brazil", scale = "medium", returnclass = "sf")
    plot(polygons_brazil)
    polygons_southamerica <- ne_countries(country = c("argentina", "bolivia", "chile", "colombia", "ecuador", "guyana", "paraguay", "peru", "suriname", "uruguay", "venezuela"), scale = "medium", returnclass = "sf")
    plot(polygons_southamerica)
    polygons_ocean <- ne_download(type = "ocean", category = "physical", returnclass = "sf")
    plot(polygons_ocean)

    # R crashes after this point (ggplot2 is processed by some time)

    map <- ggplot() +
    geom_raster(data = testdf , aes(x = x, y = y, fill = layer), show.legend = TRUE) +
    geom_sf(data = polygons_ocean, color = "transparent", lwd = 0.35, fill = "white", show.legend = FALSE) +
    geom_sf(data = polygons_brazil, color = "darkgray", lwd = 0.35, fill = "transparent", show.legend = FALSE) +
    geom_sf(data = polygons_southamerica, color = "darkgray", lwd = 0.35, fill = "gray88", show.legend = FALSE) +
    scale_fill_viridis(breaks = c(1, 11923200, 23846400, 35769600, 47692800), limits = c(1, 47692800)) +
    guides(fill = guide_colorbar(keyheight = 6, ticks = FALSE, title = bquote(delta^18 *O))) +
    ylab("Latitude") +
    xlab("Longitude") +
    coord_sf(xlim = c(-76, -28), ylim = c(-36, 8), expand = FALSE) +
    theme(axis.text.y = element_text(size = 10, color = "black"),
    axis.text.x = element_text(size = 10, color = "black"),
    axis.title.y = element_text(size = 10, color = "black"),
    axis.title.x = element_text(size = 10, color = "black"),
    legend.title = element_text(size = 10),
    legend.text = element_text(size = 9.5),
    legend.box = "vertical",
    panel.background = element_rect(fill = "white"),
    panel.grid.major = element_line(color = "gray96", size = 0.50),
    panel.grid.minor = element_line(color = "gray96", size = 0.30),
    axis.line = element_line(color = "black", size = 0.5),
    panel.border = element_rect(color = "black", fill = NA, size = 0.5)) +
    annotation_scale(location = "br") +
    annotation_north_arrow(location = "br", which_north = "true", 
    pad_x = unit(0, "cm"), pad_y = unit(0.8, "cm"),
    style = north_arrow_fancy_orienteering)
    map
    ggsave("test.png", width = 9, height = 6, units = "in", dpi = 300)
```

Could anyone help me with this?

Comment: It is difficult to help if you do not provide a minimal, self-contained, reproducible example. Can you edit your question and use example data that comes with R (see `?raster`. Presumably that won't crash, but then we at least see what you are trying to achieve. In addition, you could make `"Iso2H.tif"` available.

Comment: Many thanks for the suggestion. The R code is now reproducible since all files are available for download.

Comment: And just to make sure:  you're doing the Windows evaluation on the same box, same tooling?  Or are we comparing oranges with potatoes?

Comment: Same code on Windows, except for the addition of the first six lines to manage the memory (memory.size). Thus, we are comparing oranges with oranges or potatoes with potatoes.

Comment: Same machine, same amount of physical memory?

Comment: Yes, as Manjaro is running in dual-boot with W10. I also tested this R code (or another one using lmer function for a large dataset) on another laptop with Manjaro and the error remains.

Comment: Did you try editing ulimit etc directly on the linux machine terminal? Just to eliminate the probability that the r package isn't doing what it's saying it is. I have a feeling it might be that on windows it's letting you increase limits but on nix its blocking you for permissions. I remember hitting ulimit a lot and the only real way to fix it was to go messing with sudo and the term, then make sure I was in the right user with the right limits with rstudio

Comment: I think the "ulimit" package is working properly on R since when a low amount of memory is set (e.g., 2000 Mb), the raster file cannot be loaded as well packages, similar to this topic: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12582793/limiting-memory-usage-in-r-under-linux/24475329#24475329 It is a bit weird, because if the memory is limited to a certain amount, I cannot process some functions. Conversely, without any limitation (based on principle that Linux does not limit RAM usage like Windows), my R session crashes.

Comment: Your code still depends on external files. Can you please make it reproducible with an example file that comes with R. And the solution is surely not to manage your memory, but to reduce the data your are plotting (because you won't see the difference anyway)

Comment: The code was updated following your instruction. Please let me know if any other modification is needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of a member from another forum (https://community.rstudio.com/t/out-of-memory-on-r-using-linux-but-not-on-windows/106549), I found the solution. The crash was a result of memory limitation in the swap partition, as speculated earlier. I increased my swap from 2 Gb to 16 Gb and now R/RStudio is able to complete the whole script. It is a quite demanding task since all of my physical memory is exhausted and nearly 15 Gb of the swap is eaten.

Comment: And what was the swap usage on Windows? Just out of curiosity ...